# change unicode string into list?

Tags: python

I get the data as type `<type 'unicode'>`

```
u'{0.128,0.128,0.133,0.137,0.141,0.146,0.15,0.155,0.159,0.164,0.169,0.174,0.179,0.185,0.19,0.196,0.202,0.208,0.214,0.22}'
```

I want to convert this to list like

```
[0.128,0.128,0.133,0.137,0.141,0.146,0.15,0.155,0.159,0.164,0.169,0.174,0.179,0.185,0.19,0.196,0.202,0.208,0.214,0.22]
```

How can I do this with python?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just like that:

```
>>> a = u'{0.128,0.128,0.133,0.137,0.141,0.146,0.15,0.155,0.159,0.164,0.169,0.174,0.179,0.185,0.19,0.196,0.202,0.208,0.214,0.22}'
>>> [float(i) for i in a.strip('{}').split(',')]
[0.128, 0.128, 0.133, 0.137, 0.141, 0.146, 0.15, 0.155, 0.159, 0.164, 0.169, 0.174, 0.179, 0.185, 0.19, 0.196, 0.202, 0.208, 0.214, 0.22]
```

Unicode is very similar to `str` and you can use `.split()`, as well as `strip()`. Furthermore, casting to `float` works the way it works for `str`.

So, first strip your string of the unnecessary curly braces (`{` and `}`) by using `.strip('{}')`, then split the resulting string by commas (`,`) using `.split(',')`. After that you can just use list comprehension, converting each item to `float`, as in the example above.

Answer (score 4):

Out of my head and untested:

```
data = u'your string with braces removed'
aslist = [float(x) for x in data.split(',')]
```